# How to configure path to routes file in PlayFramework?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using PlayFramework 2.6. I wanted to use the default *sbt* directory structure so I've created my `routes` file under the /src/main/resources/ directory. How do I configure that path? Should I use `application.conf` for that?

Comment: For my own curiosity why do you want to use sbt directory structure instead of Play's out of the box mvc structure? Is there any advantage to that?

Comment: @DaveRose For learning purposes. I don't like out of the box solutions, unless I know how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the default sbt directory layout, you have to disable the `PlayLayoutPlugin` in project configuration into `build.sbt`.

Like the following:

```
lazy val play = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)
  .settings(
    ...
    // other settings
  )
```

Reference: [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Anatomy#Default-SBT-layout)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I've had `PlayService` instead of `PlayScala` enabled. For `PlayService` you need to also enable `RoutesCompiler` plugin, instead of disabling `PlayLayoutPlugin`.